# Why is this whatever put into determiner?

Tags: determiners

1. [determiner] Whatever you say is fine with me.
2. [pronoun]   I'll do whatever I can.
   ([wiktonary.org](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whatever))

It seems like the two ‘whatever’s are doing the same function as pronouns. Why does the Wiktionary put the first one into determiner category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wiktionary has two entries under *Determiner*:

1. No matter which; for any
   *Whatever choice you make, there will be consequences.*
2. (*relative*) Anything that.
   *Whatever you say is fine with me.*

The first of these undoubtedly stands in an adjectival or determinative relation to *choice*, which is the head of its "free relative" clause. "Relative determiner" appears to be a common term for words of this class.

But I agree with you that the second, the one you cite, acts as a pronoun, indistinguishable from the use in the citation under *Pronoun*.

***Why does Wiktionary call it a determiner?***
Wiktionary is crowd-composed, and it looks to me like somebody confused two different uses of the word which both head free relative clauses. The "talk" at that entry indicates that there was some shuffling around involving the *Pronoun* entry.

The confusion may also be due in part to the fact that what to call the *wh-* words which appear in this position is up in the air. McCawley, for instance, insists that they are "interrogatives"!

Comment: Should not _whatever_ be used before a noun, to be a determiner? In _whatever you say_, it is followed by a personal pronoun.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I agree with OP that in that phrase *whatever*is NOT a determiner but a pronoun. But the *you* there is not related; *you* is the Subject of *say*, *whatever* is the Direct Object of *say*.

Comment: That is how a determiner is used, though. I have never seen _a you_, _the you_ or _every you_ being used in a sentence.

Comment: @kiamlaluno It is NOT a determiner there, but a pronoun. YOUsubject SAYverb WHATEVERdirectobject, inverted as a relative clause. It IS a determiner in *Whatever choice you make*.

Comment: It's what I am saying: In "Whatever choice you make." _whatever_ is followed by a noun (and it is a determiner), but in "Whatever you say." or "You say whatever." _whatever_ is not followed by a noun.

Comment: @kiamlaluno ?? What are we arguing about ?? :)